# Validar RadioButton en PHP

Tags: php

Buen día ,

Hola,
Tengo una tabla en la primera sección (Prueba1) tengo dos radio button ejemplo opción1 y opción2 al seleccionar siguiente aparece otra tabla con dos radio Buttons pero me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer que si seleccionas opcion3 te aparezca un mensaje que no es posible porque en la sección dos seleccionaste opción1.

Cómo podría hacerlo?

Gracias.

[Prueba1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ii5d.png)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar tu código por favor?

Comment: Si por haber elegido la opción 2 en el primer formulario, no puedo elegir la opción 3 en algún formulario posterior **carece de sentido ofrecer la 3**; eso es un error de diseño y habla mal del sitio o del proyecto que la propone. Al avanzar con la opción 2 electa, la 3 debe ocultarse o mostrarse **deshabilitada**. Tu problema es hacer que el diseño sea consistente. Aprovecho para darte la bienvenida a [es.so] e invitarte a hacer el [tour] y consultar [ask]. Luego ve a [edit] y mejora tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Si no puede elegir la 3 para que la vas a mostrar?